# How to take images only within the bounding box in android custom camera

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

Recently, I found a app that captures only the images within the boxes like the image below. Should I use a SurfaceView ? or are there some other technique to do this ? I made a camera app with surfaceview and thinking about implementing a blue box like the image below so that I can take the images within the 2 blue boxes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can captures the whole image, but just crop the target area after capturing. :)

Comment: Are there some the tutorial of cropping the selected part of image in android ? Since I'm a noob I find it difficult to crop the 2 parts within those boxes.

Comment: You can find out how to crop a image [here](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage/blob/master/simple-crop-image-lib/src/eu/janmuller/android/simplecropimage/CropImage.java). see  the `onSaveClicked() ` method.