# How to save the image within the bounding box in custom android camera by cropping?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-bitmap

I've made a  custom surfaceview camera with android and want to save two parts of the images within the bounding box like the  image below. Are there a way to crop more that one part of the bounding box and save the image ?

[image]

Comment: Not sure about your actual question but you can get the bounding box coordinates and crop the image bitmap using something like this: `Bitmap newImage Bitmap.createBitmap(oldImageBitmap, 0, 0, height, width);`

Comment: one crop= one image. so you can crop two parts of start image and save them as two different bitmaps.

Comment: So for example, to get the image within the blue box like the image above. I should use 2 createBitmap()?  It might sound silly but for example like how can I set the parameters within the creatBitmap to get the desired region of the box ?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715313/how-to-take-images-only-within-the-bounding-box-in-android-custom-camera

Comment: It is similar but now I wanted to know more about cropping.